# Portable bit fields for Handles

Tags: c++, portability, endianness, unions, bit-fields

I want to use and store "Handles" to data in an object buffer to reduce allocation overhead. The handle is simply an index into an array with the object. However I need to detect use-after-reallocations, as this could slip in quite easily. The common approach seems to be using bit fields. However this leads to 2 problems:

1. Bit fields are implementation defined
2. Bit shifting is not portable across big/little endian machines.

What I need:

- Store handle to file (file handler can manage either integer types (byte swapping) or byte arrays)
- Store 2 values in the handle with minimum space

What I got:

```
template<class T_HandleDef, typename T_Storage = uint32_t>
struct Handle
{
    typedef T_HandleDef HandleDef;
    typedef T_Storage Storage;

    Handle(): handle_(0){}
private:
    const T_Storage handle_;
};

template<unsigned T_numIndexBits = 16, typename T_Tag = void>
struct HandleDef{
    static const unsigned numIndexBits = T_numIndexBits;
};

template<class T_Handle>
struct HandleAccessor{
    typedef typename T_Handle::Storage Storage;
    typedef typename T_Handle::HandleDef HandleDef;

    static const unsigned numIndexBits = HandleDef::numIndexBits;
    static const unsigned numMagicBits = sizeof(Storage) * 8 - numIndexBits;

    /// "Magic" struct that splits the handle into values
    union HandleData{
        struct
        {
            Storage index : numIndexBits;
            Storage magic : numMagicBits;
        };
        T_Handle handle;
    };
};
```

A usage would be for example:

```
typedef Handle<HandleDef<24> > FooHandle;
FooHandle Create(unsigned idx, unsigned m){
    HandleAccessor<FooHandle>::HandleData data;
    data.idx = idx;
    data.magic = m;
    return data.handle;
}
```

My goal was to keep the handle as opaque as possible, add a bool check but nothing else. Users of the handle should not be able to do anything with it but passing it around.

So problems I run into:

- Union is UB -> Replace its `T_Handle` by `Storage` and add a ctor to Handle from Storage
- How does the compiler layout the bit field? I fill the whole union/type so there should be no padding. So probably the only thing that can be different is which type comes first depending on endianess, correct?
- How can I store `handle_` to a file and load it from a possible different endianess machine and still have `index` and `magic` be correct? I think I can store the containing `Storage` 'endian-correct' and get correct values, **IF** both members occupy exactly half the space (2 Shorts in an uint) But I always want more space for the index than for the magic value.

Note: There are already questions about bitfields and unions. Summary:

- Bitfields may have unexpected padding (impossible here as whole type occupied)
- Order of "members" depend on compiler (only 2 possible ways here, should be save to assume order depends entirely on endianess, so this may or may not actually help here)
- Specific binary layout of bits can be achieved by manual shifting (or e.g. wrappers http://blog.codef00.com/2014/12/06/portable-bitfields-using-c11/) -> Is not an answer here. I need also a specific layout of the values **IN** the bitfield. So I'm not sure what I get, if I e.g. create a handle as `handle = (magic << numIndexBits) | index` and save/load this as binary (no endianess conversion) Missing a BigEndian machine for testing.

Note: No C++11, but boost is allowed.

Comment: Running a uint32_t through htonl() before saving and through ntohl() after loading would ensure that the on-disk-bits are always in stored big-endian format, regardless of the endian-ness of the CPU.

Comment: This way I get the same layout of `Storage` on the disk. But does this also mean I can safely access the 2 values in it via bit field or shifting? (Side question: Is there an online service to test such things?)

Comment: The C/C++ bit-shift operators always operate on the native-endian representation of the data, so the endian-ness of the word does not change their semantics.  Endian-ness is only an issue when the data passes from one computer to another (e.g. via network connection or by being saved to a file on one machine and loaded on another machine), and it can be handled via htonl()/ntohl() style rectifying of the endian-ness during as part of the save/restore routines.

Comment: Regarding how to test endian-ness:  I'm not aware of a such a service (doesn't mean there isn't one, I've just never heard of one), but you can also check the endian-ness of your files just by eyeballing them in a hex editor.  Save a well-known 32-bit value (e.g. 0x123456) and if it shows up in the hex editor as 00 12 34 56 then you saved it as big-endian; OTOH if it shows up in the hex editor as 56 34 12 00, you saved it as little-endian.

Comment: But the only real test of course is to actually compile and run your program on a big-endian CPU and verify that it can save/load files generated by your program that was running on a little-endian CPU (or vice versa).  If you want to do that, you might look at buying an old PowerPC Mac on eBay or somewhere, and installing Linux on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is pretty simple (based on another question I forgot the link to and comments by @Jeremy Friesner ):

As "numbers" are already an abstraction in C++ one can be sure to always have the same bit representation when the variable is in a CPU register (when it is used for anything calculation like) Also bit shifts in C++ are defined in an endian-independent way. This means `x << 1` is always equal `x * 2` (and hence big-endian)
Only time one get endianess problems is when saving to file, send/recv over network or accessing it from memory differently (e.g. via pointers...)

One cannot use C++ bitfields here, as one cannot be 100% sure about the order of the "entries". Bitfield containers might be ok, if they allow access to the data as a "number".

Savest is (still) using bitshifts, which are very simple in this case (only 2 values) During storing/serialization the number must then be stored in an endian-agnostic way.